# Using Delphi THTTPClient with TLS/SSL and own DNS host name resolving

Tags: http, delphi, ssl, dns

Is it possible to use the Delphi System.Net.HttpClient.THTTPClient class with TLS/SSL and own DNS host name resolving? At the moment I didn't get it to work. Http "Host" Header isn't enough - it seems to be a SNI issue. So I have to set the host name individually for the TLS negotiation process.

Url example:

```
https://api.ipgeolocationapi.com
-->
https://172.64.111.34
```

For the second one I have to >>set<< the host name "api.ipgeolocationapi.com" separately to avoid certificate problems. The question is how to do that.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You can modify your `hosts` file.

Comment: It is not really clear what the actual problem is. Please clarify.

Comment: Accessing a https web service just over ip is in most cases not possible because of certificate issues. So the host name must be given to the TLS handshake process. In my current project I like to have full control of the DNS name resolving etc. I use Indy IdDNSResolver for DNS client functionality for use with SMTP, SNTP, etc. Ideally I would like to use this for https as well.

Answer (score 1):

The host name is part of the HTTP request only in a header line "host". So you can simply add that header line to the request and use the IP in the URL. If Indy component add a host header line, you must change the value (which would in you case be the IP) to the host name.

Comment: The OP refers to [SNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication), which is part of the TLS negotiation. If the handshake fails because of that, the connection is closed and you don't even have the chance to send an HTTP query.

Comment: When the component starts TLS negociation, it has to find what the host name is. This can be done by parsing the URL and if an hard coded IP is given, the component should parse the header for the "host" line or provide an event to get it.

Comment: Host header unfortunately doesn't work in most cases (f.e. Google works with that, my example here with ipgeolocationapi not). The host name is part of the SNI negotiation so I have to give that information to the "process". Maybe it is possible in this section: `{ TURLRequest }
...  FLocalCredential := TCredentialsStorage.TCredential.Create(TAuthTargetType.Server, '',
    AURI.Host, AURI.Username, AUri.Password);
end;`

Comment: I've created a feature request at Embarcadero: RSP-33210 - TLS/SNI host name support in System.Net.HttpClient.THTTPClient for own DNS/IP usage